# Add one attribute [column] to an existing Entity

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Add one column to core data, at one particular condition i want to add one column to existing Entity and insert the data to that column. an new in using Core data

Comment: You'll want to look at Apple's [guide to this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html). You'll create a new version of the data model and migrate to it.

Comment: @TomHarrington ok Thank You.Am new in core data can i get a sample or steps

Comment: It's all in the documentation at the link I provided. All you have to do is look.